# Define two subsets, $A$ and $B$, of the interval $[0,1]$ (of the reals) such that their intersection, $A\cap B$, is countable. A and B are uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking something along these lines: $A = [0,1)$ and $B = (0,1]$, so their intersection would be $A\cap B = \emptyset$ (i.e. null set), which is finite and, therefore, countable. I have a feeling that I'm wrong about this, so any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The intersection of those two sets is $(0,1)$, not $\emptyset$.  But why not take $A,B = \emptyset$?  Is there some other condition you want to satisfy?

Comment: The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is $(0,1)$ in this case.

Comment: Also, it is unusual to denote the intersection $A \cap B$ by $AB$.  Is it possible you have misread the exercise?

Comment: Even if we understand "countable" as "countably infinite", this problem is trivial. Is there any other restriction, like, that both A and B should be uncountable?

Comment: @Trevor: not that unusual. The power set ${\mathcal P}(X)$ is a ${\mathbb Z}_2$-algebra for the addition $A+B=A\Delta B$ (symmetric difference) and the product $AB=A\cap B$. Although not universal, the product notation for intersections is used in many books of probabilities

Comment: @Taladris I see. The notation does make sense, but I was not aware that it was widely used.

Comment: Sorry, I indeed meant that A and B are to be taken as uncountable - fixed the title to reflect that now.

Comment: @Trevor: It isn’t widely used except in that very specific context. It used to be much more common; Sierpiński uses it, for instance, in the papers of his that I’ve seen.

Answer (score 3):

You can just take  $A=\{ \frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup (\frac{1}{2},1)$ and $B=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

$A=_c B=_c \mathbb{R}$

Then $A\cap B=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ which is countable

Comment: By $=_c$ do you mean "has the same cardinality as"?  I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Yes $=_c$ means that those 2 sets have the same cardinality. There are plenty of trivial answers indeed.